# Wicket - DatePicker extend range

Tags: java, datepicker, wiquery

A quick question.
When I create a datePicker object, the range of years you can select with DropDownChoice is a range -10/+10 years from now.

How can I extend this range? I want to start from 1900.
I tried with setMinDate but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [DatePicker](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/yui/calendar/DatePicker.html), [DatePicker.configure(Map widgetProperties, IHeaderResponse response, Map initVariables)](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/yui/calendar/DatePicker.html#configure%28java.util.Map,%20org.apache.wicket.markup.html.IHeaderResponse,%20java.util.Map%29) and [YUI Calendar](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Calendar.html), you can set the `mindate` and `maxdate` as widgetProperties.

Comment: Im using org.odlabs.wiquery.ui.datepicker.DatePicker and not org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker

Comment: @MrMime I took the liberty to fix the tags to this question accordingly.